# page content wrapper bootstrap not working on contentplaceholder in asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I have one master page here where i am applying page-content-wrapper before contentplaceholder1

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ESmartMaster.master.cs" Inherits="ESmartMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=yes, initial-scale=1"/>
<meta name="description" content=""/>
<meta name="author" content=""/>
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <!-- wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand"><a href="#">E-Smart Bankers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shortcuts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <!--navigation bar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div>                    
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle"><=</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    </ul>                        
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                        
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <%--<li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>--%>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!--/#navigation bar-->

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper" class="active">
             <div id="content">
                 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#Page Content -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script>
    <script src="js/modernizr-1.0.min.js"></script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my child page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ESmartMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AccountSummary.aspx.cs" Inherits="AccountSummary" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
          <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>TransactionID</td>
                    <td>Payee</td>
                    <td>Payer</td>
                    <td>Type</td>
                    <td>Date</td>
                    <td>Amount</td>
                    <td>Status</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="items in transaction">
                    <td>{{items.TransactionId}}</td>
                    <td>{{items.PaidFrom}}</td>
                    <td>{{items.PaidTo}}</td>
                    <td>{{items.TransactionType}}</td>
                    <td>{{items.TransactionDate}}</td>
                    <td>{{items.TransactionAmount}}</td>
                    <td>{{items.TransactionStatus}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

</div>
</asp:Content>
```

the issue is page-content-wrapper is not working on childpage but when i write this table in masterpage before contentplaceholder it is working but inside contentplaceholder of childpage it is not working
help me solve this..